# Jquery plugin for adding text on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are various jquery plugins that adds text as overlay on image. But I want to allow user to place text on image, give effect(like font, size, curve) to text and then save it as image.
Something like http://ipiccy.com/ (Don't need all the features but adding text and text effects)
I am using Asp.Net mvc. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position text, once images are loaded, even if randomly, jQuery's position() method will provide you will all the information you need.
Then you can put whatever text/effects you want in the container.

```
<h1>Text Blocks Over Image, Updated</h1>

<figure>
  <img src="http://baconmockup.com/501/351" />
  <figcaption>
    <span>
      trdy
      <span class='spacer'></span>
      <br />
      <span class='spacer'></span>
      bacon ipsum dolor sit amet
    </span>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<p>Modernized and improved from <a href="http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/">http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/</a>.</p>

<h3>Key Updates</h3>

<ul>
  <li>Positioning the <code>h2</code> by <code>bottom</code> pins the caption to the <em>bottom</em> of the image.</li>
  <li>Reset bg color declaration on spacer element.</li>
<!--   <li>Used <code>:before</code> and <code>:after</code> for line-break spacing.</li> -->
  <li>Switched to <a href="http://baconipsum.com/">http://baconipsum.com/</a> and <a href="http://baconmockup.com">http://baconmockup.com</a> for better BEO.</li>
  <li>Semantcized to figure/figcaption markup.</li>
</ul>
```